# Creating an R installer for use with a specific script

Tags: r, installation

I'm hoping to provide an r script to someone so that they can just run it and let it do its thing, but I'm concerned that there are too many opportunities for error/incompatibility if they go through the standard R installation process. I'm hoping to provide them with an installer that includes a specific version of r and specific versions of the requisite packages. Is there a straightforward way of accomplishing this?

Comment: I'd lean towards something like `packrat` or `checkpoint`, allowing you to define a specific combination of software versions. They're generally pretty good enabling a fully reproducible environment (at least, as far as package versions go) and prevent unintended "upgrades" messing with your script performance.

Comment: And while it's a little more work for you up-front, I'd "distribute" the scripts and such to them via a repo, whether GitHub, GitLab, or just some raw ssh-available `git` repo.